# Please extend tag-based highlighting for java on [javafx-8] tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I've already requested that for the [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx) and [javafx-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx-2) tags and user "Won't" kindly helped the JavaFX community. But the new tag [javafx-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx-8) suffers from the same problem now.

[Is it possible to expand tag-based highlighting for Java on javafx and javafx-2 tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129873/is-it-possible-to-expand-tag-based-highlighting-for-java-on-javafx-and-javafx-2/129882?noredirect=1#comment771196_129882)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deed is done. This affects about [100 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx-8+-java+-javafx+-javafx-2) at the moment.